# Can this onPress, called in TochableOpacity, return a Text component?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, jsx

[[image: 1]]

the image is the resultof when you console.log(this.state.fixtures)

I havent run into an error, but also havent gotten a result. Just trying to pass the individual match, from the .map(), to the Card component. Not sure if the onPress should be called in the TouchableOpacity. Been looking at this so a couple of day, any feedback s appreciated. Thank You.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardSection } from '../common';
//import ListOf from './ListOf';

export default class LeagueCard extends Component {

 state ={
  fixtures: null
 }

 componentDidMount = () => {
  const {league_name, league_id } = this.props.league 
  {this.getMatches(league_id)}
 }



 getMatches = (league_id) => {
  let legaueID = league_id
  let fixArray = []
  //console.log(legaueID)
  fetch(`https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_events&from=2016-10-30&to=2016-11-01&league_id=${legaueID}&APIkey=42f53c25607596901bc6726d6d83c3ebf7376068ff89181d25a1bba477149480`)
   .then(res => res.json())
    .then(fixtures => {
        
     fixtures.map(function(fix, id){
         
      fixArray =[...fixArray, fix]

     })
       this.setState({
        fixtures: fixArray
       })
                        console.log(this.state.fixtures)
    }) 
 }


 display = () => {
  //console.log(this.state.fixtures)
  
  if(this.state.fixtures != null){
     this.state.fixtures.map(function(match, id){
       //console.log(match)
       return (
        <Text>match</Text>
        )
   })
  }
 }

render(){
 const {league_name, league_id } = this.props.league

 return(
  <View>
  <TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => this.display()}
  >
   <Card>
    <CardSection>
     <Text>{league_name}</Text>
    </CardSection>
  
    
   </Card>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
 )}


}
```

enter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation} from 'react-native';
import {Card, CardSection} from '../common';

export default class LeagueCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fixtures: null,
      matches: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {league_name, league_id} = this.props.league;
    this.getMatches(league_id)
  };

  getMatches = (league_id) => {
    let legaueID = league_id;
    let fixArray = [];
    fetch(`https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_events&from=2016-10-30&to=2016-11-01&league_id=${legaueID}&APIkey=42f53c25607596901bc6726d6d83c3ebf7376068ff89181d25a1bba477149480`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(fixtures => {
        fixtures.map(function (fix, id) {
          fixArray = [...fixArray, fix]
        });
        this.setState({
          fixtures: fixArray
        })
      })
  };

  display = () => {
    if (this.state.fixtures != null) {
      this.setState({
        matches: this.state.fixtures.map(match => <Text>{match.country_name}</Text>)
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {league_name, league_id} = this.props.league;
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.display}>
          <Card>
            <CardSection>
              {this.state.matches}
            </CardSection>
          </Card>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I made the changes I think will render your matches for you. I made your `display()` f set the `state.matches` of your LeagueCard, which will now be an array of Text components each displaying match. The `Array.prototype.map` function in JavaScript returns a *new* array which should then be used.

Also should mention that I added a constructor where I initialize state, though that is not strictly necessary it is a good practice.

Watch out for typos too, you have one in `getMatches` which I did not fix.

Edit: I changed match to match.country_name as you can't give objects directly to a Text component. You will need to grab each key/value pair of the object you want to display.

Comment: i get some errors like ..Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {match_id, country_id, country_name, league_id, league_name, match_date, match_status, match_time, match_hometeam_name, match_hometeam_score, match_awayteam_name, match_awayteam_score, match_hometeam_halftime_score, match_awayteam_halftime_score, match_live, goalscorer, cards, lineup}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I think then I'm not understanding what the structure of your data you receive back from the fetch request is. Can you provide that in your post?

Comment: I just put the screen shot of the result of when i console.log(this.state.fixtures)

Comment: Alright I updated my answer, you can pick a value to display in your text component or you can combine multiple values into one string to display.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I have to adjust some things with the data, but im pretty sure i got . you put me on a great path . thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

this will not show any error to you, but your components will not render, because react will not know where to render it, a workaround to this problem is try something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
    import { Card, CardSection } from '../common';
    //import ListOf from './ListOf';

    export default class LeagueCard extends Component {

        state ={
            fixtures: null,
            showTextList: false
        }

        componentDidMount = () => {
            const {league_name, league_id } = this.props.league 
            {this.getMatches(league_id)}
        }



        getMatches = (league_id) => {
            let legaueID = league_id
            let fixArray = []
            //console.log(legaueID)
            fetch(`https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_events&from=2016-10-30&to=2016-11-01&league_id=${legaueID}&APIkey=42f53c25607596901bc6726d6d83c3ebf7376068ff89181d25a1bba477149480`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(fixtures => {

                        fixtures.map(function(fix, id){

                            fixArray =[...fixArray, fix]

                        })
                            this.setState({
                                fixtures: fixArray
                            })
                    }) 
        }


        display = () => {
            //console.log(this.state.fixtures)

            this.setState({showTextList: true})
        }

    render(){
        const {league_name, league_id } = this.props.league

        return(
            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.display()}
            >
                <Card>
                    <CardSection>
                        <Text>{league_name}</Text>
                       {this.state.showTextList && this.state.fixtures && 
                           this.state.fixtures.map((match, id) => (<Text>{match}</Text>))

            }
                    </CardSection>


                </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )}


    }
```

I just put the text list inside your `CardSection`, because i belive you want to render the list inside it,but feel free to put this wherewver you want

Comment: Could you explain to me how this line works ...  {this.state.showTextList && this.state.fixtures && this.state.fixtures.map((match, id) => (<Text>{match}</Text>))

Comment: of course, this line just is the same as `if(this.state.showTextList && this.state.fixture){
  this.state.fixtures.map((match, id) => (<Text>{match}</Text>))
}`

this is just a syntax to use in middle of render method to make conditional render, so the array of elements tags will render if the condition is true